# Addin to Visual Studio for visualizing a selected json string in the editor

Tags: visual-studio, json, visual-studio-addins

I've got a lot of xml files, and embedded in some elements there are json serialized objects. They are quite difficult to read and modify. So question is:

Are there any Visual Studio addins availible that can take selected json-text in the editor, and visualize it (and maybe even allow for editing)?

if not, if I must build it - are there any good starting points or samples availible?
(making a right-click command availible when text is selected, and them showing a popup)

Regards

Larsi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com